# unable to show thumbnails from youtubev3 api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make youtube clone using youtubev3 api

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Typography, Card, CardContent, CardMedia } from '@mui/material';
import{ CheckCircle } from '@mui/icons-material';
import { demoThumbnailUrl, demoVideoUrl, demoVideoTitle, demoChannelUrl, demoChannelTitle } from '../utils/constants';


const VideoCard = ({ video: { id: videoId }, snippet }) => {
  console.log(videoId, snippet);
  return (
    <Card>
      <Link to= {videoId ? `/video/${videoId}` : demoVideoUrl}>
        <CardMedia 
          image={snippet?.thumbnails?.high?.url}
          alt={snippet?.title}
          sx={{ width: 350, height: 200} }
        />
      </Link>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default VideoCard
```

I am getting something like this
[image]
The console message is:
[image]
I want thumbnails to appear here instead of white boxes. Anyone knows how to fix it?

console error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the console logs a little more closely you'll see that the passed `snippet` prop is undefined in each log. The error is saying the `CardMedia` component is missing content, a.k.a. the `image` prop is undefined.

The is resolvable by either providing a defined `snippet` prop object everywhere, or applying some conditional rendering of the `CardMedia` component.

Example:

```
const VideoCard = ({ video, snippet }) => {
  return (
    <Card>
      <Link to={video.id ? `/video/${video.id}` : demoVideoUrl}>
        {snippet?.thumbnails?.high?.url
          ? (
            <CardMedia 
              image={snippet.thumbnails.high.url}
              alt={snippet.title}
              sx={{ width: 350, height: 200 }}
            />
          )
          : demoVideoTitle
        }
      </Link>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: the console message is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'thumbnails')

Comment: @billyb It seems you are passing an undefined `snippet` prop to this `VideoCard` component. Change the ternary condition from `snippet.thumbnails?.high?.url` to `snippet?.thumbnails?.high?.url` to also do a null/undefined-check on the `snippet` prop. You may also want to double-check where this `VideoCard` component is rendered and see if you are passing all the props the component expects to receive.